# How do actor-actresses avoid bacterial and viral infections?

Tags: acting

Films and TV shows feature a lot of kisses, French kisses, and sometimes simulated sex scenes.

How do actor-actresses avoid bacterial and viral infections?

Comment: You overestimate the amount of kissing. Regardless, a simple kiss is probably less dangerous than a sneeze. As for "unsimulated sex", such actors are tested regularly for infections.

Comment: My understanding is that sex scenes in films and TV shows are usually faked with careful choreography, and almost never unsimulated. *The Brown Bunny* is a notorious exception.

Comment: Unsimulated sex is almost unheard of in mainstream content.  In terms of percentage of screen time (and therefore presumably filming time) scenes involving kissing or any intimacy is relatively small.  I think you over-estimate the risks here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainstream film actors and actresses are required to complete details about their health in order for the film to receive insurance. This includes diseases that are communicable by kissing.

> Hollywood stars had to submit questionnaires detailing whether they
> had any cold sores in a bid to stop the spread of oral herpes on set,
> the latest Sony hack has revealed.
>
> Among the new documents released by Wikileaks this week was the 'Cold
> Sore Questionnaire' which Sony required actors to fill out in order to
> get insurance ahead of a film shoot, RadarOnline reported.
>
> <sub><sup>[Which Hollywood stars have herpes? Sony hack reveals actors were asked if they had oral herpes to stop it spreading on set](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3132003/Sony-hack-reveals-actors-asked-oral-herpes-stop-spreading-set.html)</sup></sub>

> The survey titled “Cold Sore Questionnaire” looks to be a part of what
> Sony sent to actors as a “Risk Management Packet,” presumably to help
> prevent the spread of the contagious virus. Below are some of the
> example questions Sony asked actors to fill out.
>
> 1. I currently have a cold sore (describe cold sore locations):_______________
> 2. I have had the cold sore since:_____________
> 3. My last cold sore was approximately (date): ______________
> 4. I have had____cold sore breakouts over a period of _______ years.
>
> <sub><sup>[Wikileaks’ new batch of Sony files reveals a survey asking stars if they’ve had oral herpes](https://thenextweb.com/news/wikileaks-new-batch-of-sony-files-reveals-a-survey-asking-stars-if-theyve-had-oral-herpes)</sup></sub>

---

Legitimate *pornographic* productions in the US insist on a regime of STD testing as well. Since May this service has been hived off as a [separate non-profit service](https://app.passcertified.org/about_us) available to pornographic talent for free. Your PASS lasts 14 days from your last confirmed test. Other countries have [similar services](https://yoursexualhealth.co.uk/adult-performer-partnership/).

> Three porn actors tested positive for HIV in the past month, prompting
> two industry shutdowns. The first shutdown lasted a week and ended on
> Aug. 28. Then, two more actors tested positive, prompting the second
> shutdown on Sept. 6.
>
> The Free Speech Coalition, which is the porn industry trade group,
> said the actors didn't contract HIV on set or pass it to their
> partners during filming.
>
> However, the industry will increase how frequently it requires testing for sexually transmitted diseases.
>
> "Our industry protocols are designed to be conservative, and our doctors support a conservative approach, for the health and well-being of the performers," Diane Duke, the coalition's CEO, said in a statement. "While the increased testing will further ensure safer sets, it is important that we remain vigilant. Going forward, we need to constantly look to both performers, producers and health care professionals to find ways to improve our protocols."
>
> **Instead of requiring performers to undergo STD testing once every 28 days, the coalition will now require them to undergo testing every 14 days, according to The Associated Press.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Porn Industry Lifts Production Ban, Increases STD Testing](https://abcnews.go.com/blogs/health/2013/09/17/porn-industry-lifts-production-ban-increases-std-testing)</sup></sub>